# C# CRUD to MySQL - Getting back to Main Method after finishing switch methods

Tags: c#, crud

So, I'm developing this Crud for the first time to learn, I erased some stuff but you'll understand my point. The point is, I made a switch to choose what I want to do (Insert/Update/Delete/Select), and each one, for example Insert, is a method where I develop it's code to do it's function. At the end of the method I want to give the user the option to return to the Main method so he can choose what else he wants to do, what should I do at this point?

```
namespace Crud
{
    class Program
    {

        a,s.dlahflkashlfhliah // Ignore this!!

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Menu stuff, ignore this as well ");
            var option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Insert();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default");
                        break;
            }
        }

        public static void Insert()
        {
            agoihilgbakjfçasdhuoh // Ignore this!!!

            Console.Write("\nData Inserted!");

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Console.Write(" (Press any key to go back to menu.)");

            command.Connection.Open(); // sql stuff

            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // sql stuff

            Console.ReadKey();

            // do I use a return to go back to menu??? (return to the Main method)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You learn about loops :)

Comment: While loop is what you need to use.

Comment: Ty very much, nice!!!

Comment: Made the "int option = 0;" on the top of the method and then the do/while, inside the while I made a "while (option > 0 && option < 4)" and it works like a charm, thx guys!